# Set session cookie listener

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications, session-cookies

How can I say into my web, how many times a cookie is loaded? 
For example, I login with my credentials,  my jsp runs and show result... when I get result I want to say username credential like this:

```
 <% 
      String Usuario = null;
      Cookie[] cookies =request.getCookies();
      if (cookies != null){
          for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
              if(cookie.getName().equals("usuario"))
                  Usuario = cookie.getValue();

          }
      }
  if (Usuario == null)
      response.sendRedirect("Index.html");
  %>
  <h3>
      Hi <%=Usuario %>, Login Complete.
  </h3>

  <form action="Logout" method="post">
      <input type="submit" value="Logout">
  </form>
```

but If I reload page I want to count how many times cookie is reloaded so in my response I get:

```
      <h3>
          Hi <%=Usuario %>, Login Complete. + cookiecount
      </h3>
```

How can I do that?

JSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Login con Cookies</title>
</head>
<body>
  <% 
      String Usuario = null;
      Cookie[] cookies =request.getCookies();
      if (cookies != null){
          for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
              if(cookie.getName().equals("usuario"))
                  Usuario = cookie.getValue();

          }
      }
  if (Usuario == null)
      response.sendRedirect("Index.html");
  %>
  <h3>
      Hi <%=Usuario %>, Login Complete.
  </h3>

  <form action="Logout" method="post">
      <input type="submit" value="Logout">
  </form>
</body>
```

LoginServlet:

```
 @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    String user = request.getParameter("usuario");
    String contra = request.getParameter("contrasena");

    if (userID.equals(user) && password.equals(contra)){
        Cookie Gerardocookie = new Cookie("usuario",user);
        Gerardocookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60);
        response.addCookie(Gerardocookie);
        response.sendRedirect("Procesardatos.jsp");
    } else{
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<font color=red>Usuario y/o contrasena invalidas");
        rd.include(request, response);
    }
}
```

--------------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------------

JSP:

```
    <body>
     <% 

 String usuario = (String)session.getAttribute("usuario");
 if (usuario == null) {
response.sendRedirect("Index.html");
return;
 }
 AtomicInteger sessionCount = (AtomicInteger)session.getAttribute("count");
 int count = sessionCount.incrementAndGet(); // count = ++sessionCount
  %>
```

SERVLET:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        String user = request.getParameter("usuario");
        String contra = request.getParameter("contrasena");

     HttpSession session = request.getSession();
      session.setAttribute("usuario", user);
      session.setAttribute("count", new AtomicInteger());

    if (userID.equals(user) && password.equals(contra)){
        Cookie Gerardocookie = new Cookie("usuario",user);
        Gerardocookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60);
        response.addCookie(Gerardocookie);
        response.sendRedirect("Procesardatos.jsp");
    } else{
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<font color=red>Usuario y/o contrasena invalidas");
        rd.include(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are very easy to hack, so simply setting the user name in a cookie is pretty much useless for ensuring security. Any session cookie can be copied to another computer as a never-expiring cookie.

Suggest you store the user name in a session instead. Even if the cookie is stolen, it becomes useless once the server expires the session. (There are other things you can do to improve security even further.)

You can then store a second session attribute with a counter:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("usuario", user);
session.setAttribute("count", new AtomicInteger());
```

On subsequent requests you query the session:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String usuario = (String)session.getAttribute("usuario");
if (usuario == null) {
    response.sendRedirect("Index.html");
    return;
}
AtomicInteger sessionCount = (AtomicInteger)session.getAttribute("count");
int count = sessionCount.incrementAndGet(); // count = ++sessionCount
```

This is consistent with what you were asking, but it will increase the counter on *every* request to the server that does this. If all requests, other than the login page, are secured, they all do this, so you're basically counting requests.

Comment: I try to use your code to prove it... but I have an error on my jsp... check my edit please

Comment: there is my update, how can I display session times? or how can I implement code you share me into my app?

Comment: Don't do *both* cookie and sesssion. Remove the cookie code. --- When asking about an error, *include the error*, otherwise we have no idea what you're talking about. It *might* be because you didn't declare `session`. You forgot the first line.

Comment: Ahhhh. `session` is already made available to you. You don't have to get it. Same as `request` is available to you. See here for variables that are already available: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm

Comment: yap... servlet do it :D.. so It works now .. I just add  <h3> number of refresh without login <%=count%> </h3>